# Check the referrals, add the referrals to the balance and remove the referrals in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to make this work. The script has to check the users from the `users` table one by one. And then checking if they have any referrals in the `ref` table. Here is my code at the moment;

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "REMOVED";
$password   = "REMOVED";
$dbname     = "REMOVED";
$conn       = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql    = "SELECT id, username, amount FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $count   = 0;
    $kaas    = null;
    $kaas    = array();
    $sql     = "SELECT id, for_u, from_u FROM ref";
    $resultt = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (strtolower($roww['for_u']) == strtolower($row['username'])) {
            if (strtolower($roww['from_u']) != strtolower($row['username'])) {
                $count++;
                $kaas[$count] = $roww['id'];
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br>".$count."<br>";
    if ($count > 9) {
        $payout = round($count);
        $newbal = $row['amount'] + payout;
        $sql    = "UPDATE users SET amount='$newbal' WHERE id=" . $row['id'];
        $conn->query($sql);
        foreach ($kaas as $uhm) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=" . $uhm;
            $conn->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It does count the amount of referrals, I checked that. But it doesn't add it to the balance or removes it from the referral table.
If anyone could help, it would be awesome!

Comment: you can get the count in mysql query only and prevent looping on users for checking if they have referrer.

Comment: What do you mean @axcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this all in SQL by using INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'referals', u.username
FROM users u
INNER JOIN ref r
ON u.username = r.for_u
GROUP BY r.for_u
```

For every user, you'll have a `referals` column upon which you can do something with.

> **Demo** 
>   [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pJsb5LrvhoawMuXD1v8ZM3/0)

You could capture it like this:

```
foreach($results as $userResult)
{
    if($userResult['referals'] > 9)
    {
        echo "{$userResult['username']} as more than 9 referals";
    }
}
```

Your full code would look something like this:

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as 'referals', u.amount, u.username, u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN ref r ON u.username = r.for_u GROUP BY r.for_u');
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(($count = $row['referals']) > 9) {
        $payout = round($count);
        $newbal = $row['amount'] + $payout;
        $conn->query("UPDATE users SET amount='{$newbal}' WHERE id='{$row['id']}'"); # Update this new amount
        $conn->query("DELETE FROM ref WHERE for_u = '{$row['username']}'"); # Remove all referrals for this user
    }
});
```